# PyQt5 Script: Problem aligning Qlabel and coloring background

Tags: python, pyqt5

The main portion of my script looks like this:

```
def main():
    global window
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainMenu()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where `MainMenu`is a class whose definition starts as follows:

```
class MainMenu(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__()
        self.window() #window function defined below
        layout = self.frame_layout() #frame_layout function defined below

    def window(self):
        screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size() 
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, screen_width - 25, screen_height - 180) 
        self.showMaximized()        
        startup_background(self) # Inserts background image at startup (see below)
        
    def frame_layout(self):
        global frame
        frame = QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)
        frame_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        frame.setLayout(frame_layout)
        return frame_layout
```

Now for the `startup_background` function:

```
def startup_background(window):
    screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
    img_path= 'brain.png'
    pixmap = QPixmap(img_path).scaled(window.width(), 
         window.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    label = QLabel(window)
    label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) #attempt to center label in window
    label.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height()) #pixmap takes up entire label
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    label.setStyleSheet('background-color: white')
    label.show()
```

The output at the startup of my program yields this:

[image]

The problems I have are the following:

1. I can't seem to horizontally center the label in the window. Am I misunderstanding what `setAlignment` does?
2. The background color of the window outside my label is grey. I've tried using
   `setStyleSheet('background-color: white')` for the frame and for the window, but both
   cover up the label altogether.

Comment: `label.resize(window.size())`.

Comment: Note that your implementation has multiple issues. 1. if the window is resized ("unmaximized") the background will not resize; a more accurate approach should override `resizeEvent()`, call the base implementation and regenerate the pixmap based on the new size (but at that point it would be better to just override `paintEvent()`, performance wise); 2. [`window()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#window) is an existing (and important) function of all QWidgets and should **never** be overwritten; 3. you should not use globals; 4. those geometry values are totally arbitrary and unreliable; ->

Comment: besides, if you're going to maximize the window, setting the geometry is quite pointless. If you do that to set a predefined size when the window is not maximized, the point above remains (25 and 180 are based on *your* computer), if you want to prevent resizing, either use `setFixedSize()` or the appropriate `Qt.WindowFlags`. In any case, the alignment didn't work because that centers the *contents* of the label within its geometry: you are not using a layout manager (that would change the label size) but resized the label to the specific size of the pixmap, so there was nothing to align.